# Inspect file in zip archive without extracting

Tags: php, zip

I wrote a short code, which opens up a Zip File and searches for a file called "index.html".
Now I want to open the file and perform several actions.
- Search for  links.
- Search for clicktags.

Please keep in mind, that this is done while the user is uploading his file.
I dont want to extract is somewhere on the server.

Is there a good method to achieve this?
Regards

```
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip -> open($filepath);


    //Assign filescount to variable
    $this ->adFileCount = $zip -> numFiles;

    //Scan all files and find index.html
    if($zip ->getFromName("index.html") == true)
    {
        //specific action done with index.html
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the contents of the file and do whatever you need to with it.

```
$zip -> open($filepath);

for($floop = 0; $floop < $zip->numFiles; $floop++ ) {

    $stat = $zip->statIndex($floop);

    if (stripos($stat['name'],'index.html') !== false) {

        $indexcontents = $zip->getFromIndex($floop);

        //
        // do whatever you need to do with the array
        // named indexcontents that contains index.html
        //

    }

}  // end of for loop through the files in the zipped file uploaded

$zip->close();
```

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly! Could you please explain to me, what the word "index" truly means in a programing context. I searched among the internet but the definition seems to be a bit blurry.

Comment: In this context it is a pointer into the ZIP file where the file you are looking for resides. In broader terms an index points to something within something else (be it an array, a table in a database or something else). If the answer helped please accept it.